# Real number pattern (non-computable numbers)

Tags: real-analysis, computability

supposedly the real numbers have a pattern like:
[ABABA] 
where A represents rational numbers and B is irrationals s.t. $A0<B0<A1<B1<A2$.
Is there a similar pattern which includes non-computable vs computable numbers?

(Like $A0<B0<C0<A1<B1<C1<A2$,

or maybe

$A0<B0<C0<B1<A1<B1<$ etc $<A2$

or any permutation of these)

where A=rational, B=computable, C=non-computable

Comment: I’m not entirely sure what you mean by “pattern.” It is true that rationals and irrationals are dense, which implies that between any two numbers (it doesn’t matter whether either is rational or irrational), there exists a rational number (or irrational number).

Comment: Every rational number is computable, and the rational numbers are dense in the reals, so...